# Lastest Group Document belongs to

Tags: sql, group-by

I have two tables, doc_group and group (also document-table, but that is irrelevant here) and I want to get the latest Group for each Doc ID, based on Created date of the group.

| DocID | GroupID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |

| GroupID | Name | Created |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Group 1 | 1.1.2022 |
| 2 | Group 2 | 10.10.2022 |
| 3 | Group 3 | 2.2.2022 |

I have tried different approaches, but I cannot get it return the just a single line per DocID.

Here is my latest approach:

```
SELECT 
    doc_group.DocID
    ,doc_group.GroupID
    , groups.Created
FROM 
    doc_group
JOIN 
    groups 
        ON groups.ID = (
            SELECT 
                TOP 1 ID
            FROM 
                groups
            WHERE 
                groups.ID = doc_group.GroupID
            ORDER BY Created DESC           
        )
```

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result - a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join and use the row_number function as the following:

```
SELECT DocID, GroupID, Created
FROM
(
  SELECT dg.DocID ,dg.GroupID , g.Created,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dg.DocID ORDER BY g.Created DESC) rn
  FROM doc_group dg JOIN groups g
  ON dg.GroupID = g.GroupID
) T
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY DocID
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/UKDjPxhx)